# Sharing files between two war modules in the same EAR in RSA

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere-6.1, rational-rsa

My EAR has 2 WARs.

The server starts without problems, but when I try to load a page of Module-B it complains about a needed file (configuration.xml) of Module-A.

Does somebody know how to share files in classpath between two modules in the same EAR?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. 
In my case, changing WAR classloader policy from MODULE to APPLICATION in the application.xml of the EAR do the thing.